# I am not able to import LMSideBarController.h in another class

Tags: ios, xcode, class

I am trying to implement sidebar view controller. So, I downloaded code from GitHub and just dragged in my project folder.
Now I am trying to import that class

i.e `#include "LMSideBarController.h"`
or `#import "LMSideBarController.h"`

it is showing `LMSideBarController.h` file not found.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: LMSideBarController was added as reference ? Try addin it by selecting  copy items if needed option.

Comment: I added by selecting copy items if a needed option.

Comment: @MallikarjunHanagandi Sometimes it can be shown, clean and rebuild your project and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library was added as reference. Delete it and try adding it like this:

[image]

**`Select create groups option.`**

Then your library will look like this (yellow color) :

[image]

And then import , and it worked :

[image]

Comment: Got it, at the time of dragging the folder, the selection added as "create folder reference". After selecting create groups, now folder color changed to yellow color and I am able to import that class file. Thanks @sharad